# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null in

Tags: php, fatal-error

There is a problem in the code that i run. It throws this error whihc is given here:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null
>   in /home/nissah5/sjs.vedantabgp.com/includes/functions.php:25 Stack
>   trace: #0 /home/nissah5/sjs.vedantabgp.com/includes/batch.php(6):
>   searchstudent() #1 /home/nissah5/sjs.vedantabgp.com/index.php(8):
>   include('/home/nissah5/s...') #2 {main} thrown in
>   /home/nissah5/sjs.vedantabgp.com/includes/functions.php on line 25

The code that I have written is Here. 
The line no 25 refers to $query=$db->query($query);

```
function searchstudent(){
connectdb();
$condition='1'; 
if(@$_GET['y']=='xii') $condition.=" and xii='".$_GET['yr']."'";
if(@$_GET['y']=='x') $condition.=" and x='".$_GET['yr']."'";
if(@$_GET['v']=='chapter') $condition.=" and chapter='".$_GET['chapter']."'";
$query="select name, x, xii, description, id from alumni where ".$condition;
echo $query;
$query=$db->query($query);
$row1=$query->fetchAll();
$query->closeCursor();
$i=1;
foreach ($row1 as $row){ $i=($i+1)%2; if($i==0){?>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-5">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="images/templatemo_image_4.jpg" alt="image 4" />    
        </div>
<?php searchrow($row);} else{ ?>
        <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="images/templatemo_image_5.jpg" alt="image 5" />
        </div>
<?php searchrow($row);?>
    </div>
<?
}
}
if ($i==0) echo "</div>";
```

}

Echo gives this result

```
select name, x, xii, description, id from alumni where 1
```

Comment: https://secure.php.net/variables.scope !!!

Comment: Thanks that was the problem (y)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where your problem comes from in your code.. but there are 2 options that may solve this issue:

1. You can't use `WHERE and`. You need to do it like that:
   `WHERE 1=1 AND .. your condition`.
   Try change your query to:

   $query="select name, x, xii, description, id from alumni where 1=1 ".$condition;
2. You are not connected to your database and your `$db` variable is empty.

   Make sure your `connectdb();` initializes your `$db` because it's actually `null`.

Comment: How do i check if my $db is null?

Comment: Check the updated answer. and you can check it buy using `var_dump($db)` and see if it has anything it..

Comment: THanks. Problem solved.